# Laravel: Get the primary address of a user from one to many Polymorphic table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

I have two models User and Supplier. Both models have OneToMany polymorphic relations with Address model.

Tables:

suppliers

```
id - integer
name - string
```

users

```
id - integer
name - string
```

addresses

```
id - integer
is_primary - tinyint
addressable_id - integer
likeable_type - string
```

The primary address will be given and saved in addresses table when a new user created.
When modify an user, I want to get the primary address like all other data came from user table (I want to modify the primary address when modify the user) in the same form.

I want to access the address like: $user->address_line1; $user->zip; Is it possible? or how can i use the same form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar setup on my application I have a getter for the primary address in the User model.

```
public function getPrimaryAddress()
{
    return Address::firstOrNew([
        'addressable_id' => $this->id,
        'addressable_type' => User::class,
        'is_primary' => true,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I want to access the address like: $user->address_line1; $user->zip; Is it possible? or how can i use the same form?

Comment: Maybe use an accessor method `getPrimaryAddressAttribute` that simply returns `$this->getPrimaryAddress()`. Then you can do: `$user->primary_address->zip`.